# Produce a different J when using \textsl{}

Tags: text, letters, slanted

I got a problem with my bibliography.When I need to introduce the name of a journal in `\textsl{}` (or `\emph{}`), the text appears in this way:

[image]

The thing I do not like, is the letter J which looks to me like F. There is a way to use `\textsl{}` but having a J which looks like more like a J?

I hope someone could help.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: this comes from a thesis.
Here a part of the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,fleqn]{memoir}
```

The many packages used are: `amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs, mathtools, mathrsfs, latexsym, color, cite, enumitem, authblk, [capitalise]{cleveref}, tikz,pgfplots,float,caption,subcaption, microtype, xspace, pdfpages, amscd, CJKutf8, placeins, slashed`, bbm.

That text is produced when writing `\textsl{J. Differential}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,fleqn]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs, mathtools,
   mathrsfs, latexsym, color, cite, enumitem, authblk}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, float, caption, subcaption,
microtype, xspace, pdfpages, amscd, CJKutf8, placeins, slashed, bbm, dsfont,tocloft}

\begin{document}
\textsl{J. Differential}
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsl{J. Differential}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By default [you get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5u8u.png) so you are asking about code you have not shown, please always provide an example. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsl{J. Differential}
\end{document}`

Comment: The font looks like Baskerville and it has no slanted shape, so it uses italics instead. Please, make a small example of how you get that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I edited the question. Sorry, I am not an expert.

Comment: Please provide a MWE : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: no memoir does not change the font, please show, in a code block a complete small document that makes the output shown.

Comment: I made your fragments in to an example, but as you see they do not show the problem, please edit the example to generate the output you show

Comment: @DavidCarlisle also there the packages dsfont,tocloft, inconsolata, libertine, Maybe it comes from those ones?

Comment: @C.Bishop dont make people guess it is easy for you to make an example where you add the packages you need and remove the ones you do not need.